# Spark in Hortonworks does not read from HDFS when pyspark is started with Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

In an HDP cluster, I am facing the below problem. When I start pyspark with Yarn as a master, it cannot read from HDFs directory. It says directory does not exist. But if I start it without Yarn, it reads the data. Further, when I star it with yarn, it reads from hive but if I want to change the resulting DataFrame to RDD and save it to HDFs, it does not work. What is the core concept i am missing here?

**This one does not work**

```
pyspark --master yarn
rdd =sc.textFile(“HDFS path”)
rdd.first()
```

**But this one works**

```
pyspark
rdd =sc.textFile(“HDFS path”)
rdd.first()
```

Comment: Providing some more information and troubleshooting data might help you get a more targeted answer. As a quick guess, have you tried `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf` as instructed by the Hortonworks docs ? https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-access-hdfs.html

Comment: Thank you for the help. Actually, this was a certification test.